# syntax: unexpected "=" in Julia

Tags: image-processing, julia

I have written this segment of Julia code which filters keypoints in an image by an interpolation of the fields in of the extremum from a difference in gaussian scale space.

```
mutable struct discrete_extremum
    o
    s
    m
    n
    intensity
end
mutable struct candidateKeypoint
    oE
    s
    m
    n
    σ
    x
    y
    ω
end

LB = Array{candidateKeypoint}(0)
for extremum in LA′
    for i = 1:5
        H̄ = Hessian(extremum.o, extremum.s, extremum.m, extremum.n)
        ḡ = ThreeDgradient(extremum.o, extremum.s, extremum.m, extremum.n)
        α⋆ = alphaStar(H̄, ḡ)
        ω = omega(H̄, ḡ, extremum.o, extremum.s, extremum.m, extremum.n)
        δOE = δMin * 2^(extremum.o - 1)
        α1⋆ = α⋆[1]
        α2⋆ = α⋆[2]
        α3⋆ = α⋆[3]
        σ = (δOE/δMin) * σMin * 2^((α1⋆ + extremum.s)/nSpo)
        x = δOE * (α2⋆ + extremum.m)
        y = δOE * (α2⋆ + extremum.n)
        extremum.s, extremum.m, extremum.n = round(Int64, extremum.s + α1⋆), round(Int64, extremum.m + α2⋆), round(Int64, extremum.n + α3⋆)
        if max(abs(α1⋆), abs(α2⋆), abs(α3⋆)) < 0.6
            break
        end
    end
    if max(abs(α1⋆), abs(α2⋆), abs(α3⋆)) < 0.6
        push!(LB, candidateKeypoint(extremum, σ, x, y, ω))
    end
end
```

I am getting this error:

> syntax: unexpected "="

There is no line number mentioned. Can you guys suggest what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I have posted the question [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/unexpected/14225) as well.

Comment: Don't use non-ASCII names for variables. Julia may or may not officially support them, but I would bet money that it's not fully debugged

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by not fully debugged? Sorry I'm a newbee.

Comment: xref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/unexpected/14225/3

Comment: Non-ASCII unicode identifiers work perfectly well, and are widely used in the Julia community. You can _definitely_ use them. But don't go overboard. They are there to make code _more_ readable, not less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is your `α⋆, α1⋆, α2⋆, α3⋆` variables, because the symbol `⋆` is a [Julia operator](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia-parser.scm). In general, using unicode characters is fine but try to avoid using operator symbols that already have a meaning in the language.

You could replace your `α⋆` by `α′` (\alpha followed by \prime) or `̂α` (\hat followed by \alpha) for example. However, don't go overboard with non-ASCII characters. They are there to make code more readable, not less.

UPDATE: Incorporated comments by @DNF and @phg.

Comment: Maybe `\prime` or `\hat` would be OK for the OP's purpose.